# Unable to install numpy in PYCHARM ANACONDA

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm, conda

While installing numpy in my Pycharm project interpreter I am getting below error

```
File "C:\Users\2303p\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\tarball.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libarchive
File "C:\Users\2303p\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
File "C:\Users\2303p\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
File "C:\Users\2303p\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 48, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
File "C:\Users\2303p\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
File "C:\Users\2303p\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Can someone help me resolve the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pycharm, go to File, then Settings, (Ctrl + Alt + S), then click on "Project:python", then "Project Interpreter" make sure you have an active Anaconda interpreter next to the "Project Interpreter:" drop-down menu. From here you should be able to click on the "+" sign next to "Latest Version". This will open a window titled "Available Packages" from here you should be able to search for numpy then click install package.

As an alternative:
Click on terminal at the bottom of your open PyCharm application (Should be to the right of "Version Control" and to the left of "Messages")
then run the following:

```
conda install numpy
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Running from the terminal helped. Thanks a lot!!